# How can I automatically build my Docker image without including sources?

Tags: java, git, maven, docker, dockerfile

I want my Dockerfile to automatically clone my GitHub repository, use Maven to build the .jar-file and finally use said .jar-file in the image without including the source files or the Git and Maven packages.

Is this possible, or do I have to manually compile my .jar-file outside of the Dockerfile in order to copy it into the image when building it?

My goal is to have DockerHub automatically rebuild my project's image whenever I push new code to it.

At the moment, my Dockerfile installs Git and Maven, clones my repository and compiles the .jar-file. This works fine, but does not feel like the optimal solution since the Git and Maven packages stay installed in the image.

```
#Where we start
FROM openjdk:12-alpine

#Get APK up to date
RUN apk update && apk upgrade

#Install Maven
RUN apk add maven

#Git
RUN apk add git
RUN mkdir /HungryBoiiGit
RUN git clone https://github.com/hannesknutsson/HungryBoii.git /HungryBoiiGit

#Build
RUN mvn -f /HungryBoiiGit clean install

#Save result
RUN mkdir /Executables
RUN cp -r /HungryBoiiGit/target/HungryBoii-distributable/* /Executables

#Remove Git repo
RUN rm -rf /HungryBoiiGit

#Add user and group for running as unprivileged user
RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup
USER appuser

#Define how to start
WORKDIR /Executables
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "HungryBoii-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I understand there are maven plugins that build and push the Docker image whenever I decide to build my project, but that's just not really how I want to do this. I want the automated build on DockerHub to do it for me, without any packages or sources to be included.

Comment: One method is to use a multistage build. https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for!

Make this a reply and I will mark it as correct. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use a multistage build as described here: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/.

A multistage build allows you to install build dependencies and build your release artifacts in one stage, and then copy just the build artifacts to the final image.

For example:

```
#Where we start
FROM openjdk:12-alpine AS builder

#Get APK up to date
RUN apk update && apk upgrade

#Install Maven
RUN apk add maven

#Git
RUN apk add git
RUN mkdir /HungryBoiiGit
RUN git clone https://github.com/hannesknutsson/HungryBoii.git /HungryBoiiGit

#Build
RUN mvn -f /HungryBoiiGit clean install

# Build release image
FROM openjdk:12-alpine

#Copy result
WORKDIR /Executables
COPY --from=builder /HungryBoiiGit/target/HungryBoii-distributable .

#Add user and group for running as unprivileged user
RUN addgroup -S appgroup && adduser -S appuser -G appgroup
USER appuser

#Define how to start
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "HungryBoii-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Comment: Thank you!
This was, as I mentioned before, exactly what I was looking for and worked like a charm!